# RTSP on Wowza 3.4

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp

Hello i recently i took over a job for a website maintaining.Website streams live video on educational purposes. It's working on Wowza Serer v3.4 i need to show videos on mobile devices. I made a little search about this issue and found out it is possible and easy to configure on Wowza v4 by using RTSP instead of RTMP. I was wondering if it is possible on v3.4? Maybe with a help of a plugin? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Wowza will give out RTSP in the version 3 also. No need of any new plugins.

```
rtsp://[wowza-ip-address]/vod/mp4:sample.mp4
```

Try opening the above demo video on Android device.